# Firebase role that only allows a user to edit the database, but not deploy to hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Question is self explanatory. Can I only give one group of users access to deploy to hosting? Is this possible using the IAM rules?

Comment: This is not currently possible, but is something we're working toward. I can't comment on any specific timeline, but we're exploring improved IAM access to Firebase features and the Firebase Console.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh thank you.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh sounds like an answer!